# Iterate over even indices in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say i have this list:

```
CP = [1,0,1,0]
```

How can i print only 0's in the list via indices i.e CP[i].

Required output:

```
0
0
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the specified question at all 1 is iterating other is returning 2 lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feels like a homework problem, and I assume you actually want odd indices instead of even indices.

Here's a possible solution:

```
# get a range of all odd numbers between 1 and length of list
# with a step size of 2
for i in range(1, len(CP), 2):
    print(CP[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

The one liner --

```
print ('\n'.join([str(CP[i]) for i in range(1, len(CP), 2)]))
```